# why dataset.output_shapes returns demension(none) after batching

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using the Dataset API for input pipelines in TensorFlow (version: r1.2). I built my dataset and batched it with a batch size of 128. The dataset fed into the RNN.

Unfortunately, the  *`dataset.output_shape`* returns dimension(none) in the first dimension, so the RNN raises an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled1.py", line 188, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/home/harold/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow_py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "untitled1.py", line 121, in main
    run_training()
  File "untitled1.py", line 57, in run_training
    is_training=True)
  File "/home/harold/huawei/ConvLSTM/ConvLSTM.py", line 216, in inference
    initial_state=initial_state)
  File "/home/harold/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow_py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 566, in dynamic_rnn
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/harold/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow_py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 636, in _dynamic_rnn_loop
    "Input size (depth of inputs) must be accessible via shape inference,"
ValueError: Input size (depth of inputs) must be accessible via shape inference, but saw value None.
```

I think this error is caused by the shape of input, the first dimension should be batch size but not none.

here is the code:

```
origin_dataset = Dataset.BetweenS_Dataset(FLAGS.data_path)
train_dataset = origin_dataset.train_dataset
test_dataset = origin_dataset.test_dataset
shuffle_train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
shuffle_batch_train_dataset = shuffle_train_dataset.batch(128)
batch_test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(FLAGS.batch_size)

iterator = tf.contrib.data.Iterator.from_structure(
                           shuffle_batch_train_dataset.output_types,
                            shuffle_batch_train_dataset.output_shapes)
(images, labels) = iterator.get_next()

training_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(shuffle_batch_train_dataset)
test_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(batch_test_dataset)

print(shuffle_batch_train_dataset.output_shapes)
```

I print `output_shapes` and it gives:

```
(TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(36), Dimension(100)]), TensorShape([Dimension(None)]))
```

I suppose that it should be 128, because I have batched dataset:

```
(TensorShape([Dimension(128), Dimension(36), Dimension(100)]), TensorShape([Dimension(128)]))
```

Comment: How come `shuffle_batch_test_dataset` (of which you're printing the shape) isn't defined in your snippet? Did you mean `shuffle_batch_train_dataset` instead?

Comment: yes， I mean shuffle_batch_train_dataset.

Comment: I think having the first dimension as `None` shouldn't cause the issue and it looks like it's the expected behaviour when looking at the code. The error you're getting might be caused by the fact that the input you're feeding to your dynamic_rnn has undefined dimensions which are not the batch size. Could you include the code where you setup the RNN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They hardcoded batch size in implementation and it always will return None (tf 1.3).

```
def _padded_shape_to_batch_shape(s):
  return tensor_shape.vector(None).concatenate(
      tensor_util.constant_value_as_shape(s))
```

In this way, they can batch all elements (e.g. `dataset_size=14`, `batch_size=5`, `last_batch_size=4`).

You can use dataset.filter and dataset.map to fix this issue

```
d = contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([[5] for x in range(14)])
batch_size = 5
d = d.batch(batch_size)
d = d.filter(lambda e: tf.equal(tf.shape(e)[0], batch_size))
def batch_reshape(e):
    return  tf.reshape(e, [args.batch_size] + [s if s is not None else -1 for s in e.shape[1:].as_list()])
d = d.map(batch_reshape)
r = d.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
print('dataset_output_shape = %s' % r.shape)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        print(sess.run(r))
```

> **Output**
>
> *dataset_output_shape = (5, 1)*
>
> *[[5][5][5][5][5]]*
>
> *[[5][5][5][5][5]]*
>
> *OutOfRangeError*

Comment: There is a new function which does this [tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/batch_and_drop_remainder)

Comment: As of tensorflow 1.10, the `drop_remainder` parameter has been added to `tf.data.Dataset.batch` so you don't need to use the specific ` tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder`.

Answer (score 3):

This feature has been added with the [`drop_remainder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset#batch) parameter used like the following:

```
batch_test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(FLAGS.batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
```

From the docs:

> drop_remainder: (Optional.) A tf.bool scalar tf.Tensor, representing whether the last batch should be dropped in the case its has fewer than batch_size elements; the default behavior is not to drop the smaller batch.